# Popup spilling over container

Tags: jquery, css

I have a popup that dynamically creates a fixed background which holds a centred dialog. It works as intended but on small monitors (small laptops and tablets/phones) the content can run outside the viewable area and due to their fixed container become unaccessible. The problem is most acute on smaller android devices as trigging the form input in the popup as this creates the Android keypad cutting the screen real estate in half.

I've tried various solutions, for instance setting a max-height on the dialog and setting overflow-y to scroll, but on monitors that can fit the full popup this cuts it off and spoils the cosmetics.

Are there any easy wins I'm missing here? Am happy to deploy CSS or jQuery solution.

JSfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/L77v4caL/9/

Video of issue: https://youtu.be/LW9EeMVarcM (unable to scroll to the bottom of the popup, it simply gets cut off.)

Full HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    /* If button is clicked create dialog */
    $('.button').click(function () {
        /* Create background */
        $('body').prepend('<div id="dialog-bg"></div>');
        /* Create popup & form */
        $('#dialog-bg').append('<div class="dialog"><h2>Popup banner</h2><div class="large-content">This could be a large form or an iFrame to a youtube video<form><input name="email" placeholder="Form example" required=""></form></div></div>').hide().fadeIn(500);
        /* Create close button */
        $('.dialog').prepend('<div class="close-dialog"><a class="close" href="/">x</a></div>');
        /* Remove default link behaviour from close button */
        $('a.close').click(function () {
            return false;
        });
        /* Close all on click */
        $('.close, .close-dialog').click(function () {
            $('#dialog-bg, .dialog, .close-dialog .close').remove();
        });
    });
});
</script>
<style>
#dialog-bg {
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12645552/overlay.png) 0 0 repeat;
}

.dialog {
    width: 350px;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px auto 0;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.large-content {
    color: #fff;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #000;
}

.close-dialog {
    z-index: 1;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    right: 15px;
    top: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

a.close {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    line-height: 1.2;
    font-family: arial;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.button {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #2599ca;
}

.button:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus eleifend felis at aliquet rhoncus. Nunc gravida in augue et rhoncus. Nam leo ex, pretium a neque eu, accumsan efficitur ligula. Mauris sodales nulla at orci pharetra vehicula. Vivamus quis odio at mi venenatis varius. Proin nec tristique odio. Donec dictum suscipit odio et rutrum. Quisque rutrum vestibulum diam, sit amet porttitor nulla volutpat ut. Fusce mattis enim eget pulvinar congue. Nunc euismod sapien ut blandit egestas. Integer in tempor est. In quis enim at quam ornare maximus ac eget mauris.</p>
<p>Maecenas quis mollis nulla. Suspendisse quis bibendum dolor, quis tempor elit. Morbi dolor ante, dignissim eu orci in, pretium sagittis massa. Nullam tincidunt tortor vel bibendum feugiat. Quisque a dolor nec ante imperdiet ullamcorper. Fusce ac risus congue, gravida ex sed, mattis erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean ullamcorper nisl eu interdum egestas. Donec a porta justo. Maecenas dapibus lacus non odio iaculis mollis. Integer a cursus magna. Vestibulum sollicitudin, urna nec consequat convallis, dui dolor lacinia enim, sit amet mattis diam nunc non justo. Aenean finibus, nisi vel feugiat venenatis, magna nisl lobortis massa, sed vestibulum tellus ex ac tellus. Etiam a risus facilisis, congue ex vel, pretium ipsum. Suspendisse eget sapien nisi. Sed rhoncus tortor ut velit volutpat feugiat.</p>
<p>Praesent consequat justo quis magna ultrices fringilla. Nam ullamcorper sit amet massa nec finibus. Sed enim neque, dictum ullamcorper accumsan a, fringilla quis turpis. Nam et consequat tellus. In nibh lectus, malesuada congue tortor sed, aliquam fringilla enim. Sed euismod nisi et lectus rhoncus, nec pharetra tortor pulvinar. Cras pretium ullamcorper lorem nec fringilla.</p>
<p>Mauris venenatis sem nibh, in fringilla enim tempus quis. Nullam et tellus pretium, dictum nunc vel, venenatis ipsum. Pellentesque congue libero ac lobortis maximus. Nam tincidunt euismod facilisis. Cras volutpat, augue vitae consectetur tempor, libero augue placerat nunc, eu placerat ex lacus nec nulla. Pellentesque nisl nisi, tempus ac scelerisque in, vestibulum in libero. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
<p>Nam elementum lectus est, id porttitor magna tempor id. Ut metus orci, sagittis sagittis venenatis sit amet, pulvinar eu eros. Suspendisse sed gravida purus. In tincidunt urna elit. Maecenas at malesuada nisl. Donec ut congue risus. Etiam volutpat efficitur facilisis. Donec tellus nibh, sodales vel gravida ut, ullamcorper quis sapien. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec ultrices mauris at pulvinar tempus. Donec pretium, lectus vel laoreet feugiat, felis sapien dapibus augue, at pellentesque diam lorem dapibus ipsum. Nulla sit amet mattis ante, sit amet vestibulum nisi.</p>
<div class="button">Click me</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "cuts it off"? The fiddle looks fine.

Comment: In this example: http://s9.postimg.org/sy9k6un9b/Screen_Shot_2015_09_14_at_13_35_08.png I cannot scroll down to see the missing content as the popup container is fixed.

Comment: remove the width from .dialog css, make it width:80%, you may also remove the height present in .large-content.

Comment: Remove the height from .dialog and .large-content. Then the box will take the height by content inside it.

Comment: Try adding:

max-height: 100%;
overflow: auto;

to .dialog

Comment: The height in large content is there to simluate content that is found in the actual popup (like large Youtube iframes) so I can't remove that. '.dialog' doesn't have height assigned, I assume you mean '#dialog-bg'? I've removed that, still unable to see the bottom of the popup: http://jsfiddle.net/L77v4caL/10/

Comment: Caedmon: http://jsfiddle.net/L77v4caL/11/ still the same issue.

Comment: I've added a quick video to demo the issue: https://youtu.be/LW9EeMVarcM. Basically I can't scroll to the bottom of the popup.

Comment: try this css in your last fiddle    .dialog {
  background-color: #fff;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 80%;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 80%;
}

Comment: Thats almost their: http://jsfiddle.net/L77v4caL/14/. I've also defined a max height so it doesn't always fill up so much of the screen. Although not perfect (I will have to set up a variety of max-heights for each popup I think this might be workable. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, add overflow-y in `#dialog-bg` and change the following in `.dialog`

```
#dialog-bg{
    overflow-y:scroll;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12645552/overlay.png) 0 0 repeat;
}

    .dialog {
        width: 350px;
        padding: 20px;
        background-color: #fff;
        position: absolute;
        margin: auto;
        top:0;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
        right:0;
    }
```

Comment: That allows me to scroll to the bottom so partially fixes things, however it always makes the popup the height of the screen which looks odd cosmetically: http://jsfiddle.net/L77v4caL/12/

Comment: try adding add max-height:90%; in .dialog{}

Answer (score 0):

Add this, this should be able to scroll you on the popup. you can make the cosmetic changes as per the content, and try playing with height in the content.

## dialog-bg{overflow:scroll;}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, with the help of various comments I've got a working solution together: http://jsfiddle.net/L77v4caL/14/

It means I have to manually set a max-height to each popup but other than that seems fine.

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        /* If button is clicked create dialog */
        $('.button').click(function () {
            /* Create background */
            $('body').prepend('<div id="dialog-bg"></div>');
            /* Create popup & form */
            $('#dialog-bg').append('<div class="dialog"><h2>Popup banner</h2><div class="large-content">This could be a large form or an iFrame to a youtube video<form><input name="email" placeholder="Form example" required=""></form></div></div>').hide().fadeIn(500);
            /* Create close button */
            $('.dialog').prepend('<div class="close-dialog"><a class="close" href="/">x</a></div>');
            /* Remove default link behaviour from close button */
            $('a.close').click(function () {
                return false;
            });
            /* Close all on click */
            $('.close, .close-dialog').click(function () {
                $('#dialog-bg, .dialog, .close-dialog .close').remove();
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <style>
    #dialog-bg {
    overflow-y:scroll;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12645552/overlay.png) 0 0 repeat;
}

.dialog {
    background-color: #fff;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 80%;
    max-height: 450px;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 80%;
}

.large-content {
    color: #fff;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #000;
}

.close-dialog {
    z-index: 1;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    right: 15px;
    top: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

a.close {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    line-height: 1.2;
    font-family: arial;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.button {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #2599ca;
}

.button:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus eleifend felis at aliquet rhoncus. Nunc gravida in augue et rhoncus. Nam leo ex, pretium a neque eu, accumsan efficitur ligula. Mauris sodales nulla at orci pharetra vehicula. Vivamus quis odio at mi venenatis varius. Proin nec tristique odio. Donec dictum suscipit odio et rutrum. Quisque rutrum vestibulum diam, sit amet porttitor nulla volutpat ut. Fusce mattis enim eget pulvinar congue. Nunc euismod sapien ut blandit egestas. Integer in tempor est. In quis enim at quam ornare maximus ac eget mauris.</p>
    <p>Maecenas quis mollis nulla. Suspendisse quis bibendum dolor, quis tempor elit. Morbi dolor ante, dignissim eu orci in, pretium sagittis massa. Nullam tincidunt tortor vel bibendum feugiat. Quisque a dolor nec ante imperdiet ullamcorper. Fusce ac risus congue, gravida ex sed, mattis erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean ullamcorper nisl eu interdum egestas. Donec a porta justo. Maecenas dapibus lacus non odio iaculis mollis. Integer a cursus magna. Vestibulum sollicitudin, urna nec consequat convallis, dui dolor lacinia enim, sit amet mattis diam nunc non justo. Aenean finibus, nisi vel feugiat venenatis, magna nisl lobortis massa, sed vestibulum tellus ex ac tellus. Etiam a risus facilisis, congue ex vel, pretium ipsum. Suspendisse eget sapien nisi. Sed rhoncus tortor ut velit volutpat feugiat.</p>
    <p>Praesent consequat justo quis magna ultrices fringilla. Nam ullamcorper sit amet massa nec finibus. Sed enim neque, dictum ullamcorper accumsan a, fringilla quis turpis. Nam et consequat tellus. In nibh lectus, malesuada congue tortor sed, aliquam fringilla enim. Sed euismod nisi et lectus rhoncus, nec pharetra tortor pulvinar. Cras pretium ullamcorper lorem nec fringilla.</p>
    <p>Mauris venenatis sem nibh, in fringilla enim tempus quis. Nullam et tellus pretium, dictum nunc vel, venenatis ipsum. Pellentesque congue libero ac lobortis maximus. Nam tincidunt euismod facilisis. Cras volutpat, augue vitae consectetur tempor, libero augue placerat nunc, eu placerat ex lacus nec nulla. Pellentesque nisl nisi, tempus ac scelerisque in, vestibulum in libero. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
    <p>Nam elementum lectus est, id porttitor magna tempor id. Ut metus orci, sagittis sagittis venenatis sit amet, pulvinar eu eros. Suspendisse sed gravida purus. In tincidunt urna elit. Maecenas at malesuada nisl. Donec ut congue risus. Etiam volutpat efficitur facilisis. Donec tellus nibh, sodales vel gravida ut, ullamcorper quis sapien. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec ultrices mauris at pulvinar tempus. Donec pretium, lectus vel laoreet feugiat, felis sapien dapibus augue, at pellentesque diam lorem dapibus ipsum. Nulla sit amet mattis ante, sit amet vestibulum nisi.</p>
    <div class="button">Click me</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```